# Nginx Joomla Internationalization URL rewriting

Tags: joomla, url-rewriting, nginx, multilingual

I'm using Joomla in combination with Nginx, and I'm currently trying to achieve some URL rewriting for a website that has several langages supported (italian, french, chinese, and deutch)

The urls have the country code after the domain name, like so :
    `http://www.example.com/fr/test/test.html`
    or
    `http://www.example.com/de/test/test.html`

I'm looking to rewrite the urls so the country code is part of the subdomain :
    so
    `http://www.example.com/fr/test/test.html`
    becomes
    `http://fr.example.com/test/test.html`

Is there a way to achieve this with Nginx or should I look into a third party extension for Joomla (not my favorite choice).

Thanks !!

**Update :**
I wasn't clear enough : I wanted the redirection from the rewrited URL to be transparent. Here is what I came up with, thanks to VBart help :

```
server {  
  server_name ~^(?<lang>.+)\.example\.com$;  
  location / {  
    rewrite /(.*)$ /$lang/$1 break;  
    proxy_pass http://www.example.com;  
    proxy_redirect http://www.example.com http://$lang.example.com/$request_uri;  
  }  
}
```

Now, is there a way for Nginx to modify links on the fly in the served content ? ie: I want all the link in the generated page to look like `http://fr...` instead of `http://.../fr/...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
server {
    server_name ~^(?<lang>.+)\.example\.com$;
    ...
}

server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    rewrite ^/(?<lang>[a-z]+)(?<rest>.+)$ http://$lang.example.com$rest? permanent;
}
```

opposite example:

```
server {
    server_name ~^(?<lang>.+)\.example\.com$;
    return 301 http://www.example.com/$lang$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, but that seems to do the opposite of what I want. Let me explain :  when I type `http://fr.example.com/test/test.html`, in the URL bar, I want my Nginx to display the page `http://www.example.com/fr/test/test.html`. With your solution it seems that when I type `http://www.example.com/fr/test/test.html`, I'm redirected to `http://fr.example.com/test/test.html` which does not exists. Do I have to create a new server declaration for each langage?

Comment: By the way, what does the `(?<lang>)` stands for ? Does it assigns everything captured by the parenthesis to the variable `$lang` ?

Comment: *Does it assigns everything captured by the parenthesis to the variable $lang?*
Yes. (see `man pcresyntax`)

Comment: Ok, I added the opposite example. Is it what you want?

Comment: By the look of it, it seems to do what I want, but it does not work when I try it. I also have this rewriting directive : `location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args; }` Maybe that's the one conflicting ?

Comment: I don't see any problem in your config. So, how did you test it? What did you tried and what did you see? Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: Ok. I see. You also need **DNS record** for your sub domains.
http://pastebin.com/FNLbVj4z

Comment: Do you think I have to create one server declaration per subdomain ?

Comment: I've done it ! My question wasn't correct in the first place, I wanted a transparent redirect for the user. I am using `proxy_pass` and `proxy_redirect` combined to your regexp and it works like a charm ! See my updated first post ! Now, do you know if there is a way to change all the links in the generated page so they now look like my new URL? ie: `http://fr....` instead of `http://...com/fr/...` ?

Comment: You can try this: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html
but the better way is to change your backend.

Comment: Whoa nice solution.  Would love love love to see a write up of this in docs.joomla.org or a magazine article.